# convert csv file to excel using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to convert a csv file to excel using powershell.  I got some help from another post and the script runs, but the output is a blank xlsx file.

Can someone help please?

Here is the powershell script

```
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$inputfile,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$outputfile
)

$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false

$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$ws = $wb.Sheets.Item(1)

$ws.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"

write-output "Opening $inputfile"

$i = 1
Import-Csv $inputfile | Foreach-Object { 
$j = 1
foreach ($prop in $_.PSObject.Properties)
{
    if ($i -eq 1) {
        $ws.Cells.Item($i, $j) = $prop.Name
    } else {
        $ws.Cells.Item($i, $j) = $prop.Value
    }
    $j++
}
$i++
}

$wb.SaveAs($outputfile,51)
$wb.Close()
$excel.Quit()
write-output "Success"
```

Then I'm running the following command

.\csv_to_excel.ps1 -inputfile "C:\Scripts\testcsv.csv" -outputfile "C:\Scripts\data.xlsx"

Also, if anyone has experience with the Import Excel powershell module and has some kind of guide for that, I would appreciate that as well.

Thanks

Comment: `$ws.Cells.Item($i, $j)` -> `$ws.Cells.Item($i, $j).Value`

Comment: That seemed to work but it's only putting the first line of the csv file into the xlsx file and not the second line :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the Excel Module by Doug Finke from a computer with PowerShell 5 or a lower version with [PSGet](https://github.com/psget/psget/) installed:

```
Install-Module importexcel
Import-CSV $inputfile | Export-Excel $outputfile
```

Where `$inputfile` and `$outputfile` are the file locations like your script

Comment: You Rock!!!! Woot, that worked, will need to look into the pivot table parts of the module, but is that basically the same concept?

Comment: Yeah, it's just a couple parameters `-pivotrows`,`-pivotcolumns`, and `-pivotdata`. Good info about it on [Doug's github site](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Do you have to use those parameters in conjunction with either Import or Export excel?  Trying to look at github site but not seeing info on formatting.

Comment: With Export-Excel. There are a couple examples in the help `get-help Export-Excel -examples`

Comment: I get the exact same output format as the input. This did not have delimiting...

Answer (score 0):

#As an example of an EASY way to format to excel merely use "Export-Excel"

'Get-Service -ComputerName localhost |Select-Object -Property Status,Name,DisplayName|Export-Excel -Path '.\output.xlsx'

#Voila!

Comment: Sometimes the easiest way is DIRECT